# kabir was lover of lord Ram, and this is established fact why then now this upstart by Rampal call kabir as god

Tags: vedas, vishnu, krishna, kali-yuga, shloka

as by popular belief kabir was devoted to lord Ram. what has made into people believe that kabir is god

Comment: Even Chaitanya dev loved krishna does that make him not god

Comment: does so loving krishna makes every individual god, its NOT, right . Sri chaitanya mahaprabhu is god because its mentioned in scriptures like srimad bhagvatam , on the authority of sadhu , shashtra and sadhu sanga . it is accepted that sri chaitanya mahaprabhu is god , but in case of kabir it is not mentioned any where that he is incarnation or god himself , so how can people  believe him to be god , isnt is misleading people who are not well versed with science of bhakti.

Comment: There is a debate whether chaitanya mahaprabhu was God or not